# Checking subsets in cassandra

Tags: database, cql, cassandra-2.0

```
   -----------------------------
   |ID|        Team      
   -----------------------------
   |1 |       {'b'} 
   |2 |       {'c'}       
   |3 |       {'b','c'} 
   ------------------
```

I have this table in cassandra. I want to remove all subsets in the table.Since `{'b'}` is a subset of `{'b','c'}` and `{'c'}` is a subset of `{'b','c'}`, both rows 1 and 2 should be deleted.

```
   -----------------------------
   |ID|        Team      
   -----------------------------

   |3 |       {'b','c'} 
   ------------------
```

How can I perform this operation in CQL.

Answer (score 0):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    team list<text>
) ;

CREATE INDEX del_team_idx ON keyspace1.sample (team);
```

SELECT * FROM  del ;

```
 id | team
----+------------
  1 |      ['b']
  2 | ['c', 'd']
  3 | ['b', 'e']
```

**Output**

```
 SELECT * FROM sample WHERE team CONTAINS 'e' and team contains 'b' allow filtering;

 id | team
----+------------
  3 | ['b', 'e']
```